# Need help positioning the menu links in the footer

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having trouble with my footer menu links and social icon buttons. I created the footer so that it will stretch across the entire browser window. However now when I lay the menu links and social media icons inside the div they are moving whenever the page is re-sized. What do I need to do in order to make the placement of the menu links and social media links stay in the proper place?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>MECA Basketball Club</title>

<script type="text/javascript"     
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/infinite-rotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/infinite-rotator-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/infinite-rotator-3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/infinite-rotator-4.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background-image: url(img/backgroundimg.png);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        /*background-color:white;*/
    }

    #maincontainer
    {
        width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #header
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 47px;
        background-image: url(img/headerimg.png);
    }

    #headerlogo
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 201px;
        height: 118px;
        background-image: url(img/headerlogo_padding.png);
    }


    #header-nav-menu
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 580px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 400px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-1
    {
        float: right;
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 125px;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-2
    {
        float: right;
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 104px;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-3
    {
        float: right;
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 105px;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-1:hover
    {
        color: #d4d3d2;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-2:hover
    {
        color: #d4d3d2;
    }

    .nav-button-header-menu-3:hover
    {
        color: #d4d3d2;
    }

    #main-nav-container
    {
        width: 197px;
        height: 500px;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 95px;
    }



    #mainnav
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 8px;
    }

    .navbutton-red-top
    {
        /*Button Style*/
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 193px;
        background-color: #c41002;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: #a30e03;
        /*Text Style*/
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*Making Button Fancy*/
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #515050;
    }

    .navbutton-red
    {
        /*Button Style*/
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 193px;
        background-color: #c41002;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: #a30e03;
        /*Text Style*/
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*Making Button Fancy*/
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #515050;
    }

    .navbutton-black
    {
        /*Button Style*/
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 193px;
        background-color: black;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: #515050;
        /*Text Style*/
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*Making Button Fancy*/
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #515050;
    }

    .navbutton-black-bottom
    {
        /*Button Style*/
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 193px;
        background-color: black;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: #515050;
        /*Text Style*/
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        /*Making Button Fancy*/
        border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #515050;
    }


    .navbutton-red-top:hover
    {
        background: #e91101;
    }

    .navbutton-red:hover
    {
        background: #e91101;
    }

    .navbutton-black:hover
    {
        background: #2c2b2b;
    }

    .navbutton-black-bottom:hover
    {
        background: #2c2b2b;
    }

    #content
    {
        background-color: white;
        width: 1024px;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #515050;
    }

    #rotating-item-wrapper
    {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 240px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 150px;
    }

    .rotating-item
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #placeholderdiv
    {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    #slideshow
    {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    #video1
    {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    .stats-offense
    {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    #events1
    {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    #rotating-item-wrapper-2
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 455px;
        top: 281px;
    }

    .rotating-item-2
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #rotating-item-wrapper-3
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 240px;
        top: 532px;
        padding: 300px;
    }

    .rotating-item-3
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .stats-defense
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 766px;
        top: -68px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-bottom: 206px;
    }

    #rotating-item-wrapper-4
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 240px;
        top: -260px;
        padding: 35px;
    }

    .rotating-item-4
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
    }



    #footer-home
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -600px;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url(img/footerimg.png);
    }

    #footer-nav-menu-left
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 430px;
    }

    #footer-nav-menu-right
    {
        position: absolute;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 550px;
    }

    .nav-button-footer
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .nav-button-footer:hover
        {
            color: #c5c5c4;
        }

    #SocialMedia
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        color: white;
    }

    #Facebook-icon
    {
    }

    #Twitter-icon
    {
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="header"></div>

    <div id="headerlogo"></div>
    <ul id="header-nav-menu">
        <li><a class="nav-button-header-menu-3" href="#RegisterLeague">Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-button-header-menu-2" href="#RegisterLeague">Join The
Club</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-button-header-menu-1" href="#RegisterLeague">Register  
League</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content">
        <div id="main-nav-container">

            <ul id="mainnav">
                <li><a class="navbutton-red-top" href="#stats">STATS</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-red" href="#stats">EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-red" href="#stats">FIND A LEAGUE</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-red" href="#stats">SCHEDULE</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-black" href="#stats">BECOME A REFEREE</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-black" href="#stats">REGISTER LEAGUE</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbutton-black-bottom" href="#stats">JOIN THE CLUB</a>  
</li>

            </ul>
        </div>




        <div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
            <img class="rotating-item" src="img/ContentArea1/AdOne/MainAd1.png" />
            <img class="rotating-item" src="img/ContentArea1/AdOne/MainAd2.png" />
        </div>


        <div id="video1">
            <img src="img/ContentArea1/Video/video1img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="stats-offense">
            <img src="img/ContentArea1/Stats/stats1img.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="events1">
            <img src="img/ContentArea1/Events/events1.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="rotating-item-wrapper-2">
            <img class="rotating-item-2" src="img/ContentArea1/AdTwo/Ad2Img.png" />
            <img class="rotating-item-2" src="img/ContentArea1/AdTwo/Ad23Img.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="rotating-item-wrapper-3">
            <img class="rotating-item-3" src="img/ContentArea1/AdThree/Ad3Img.png" />
            <img class="rotating-item-3" src="img/ContentArea1/AdThree/Ad4Img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="stats-defense">
            <img src="img/ContentArea1/Events/events1.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="rotating-item-wrapper-4">
            <img class="rotating-item-4" src="img/ContentArea1/VBanner/vbanner1img.png" 
/>
            <img class="rotating-item-4" src="img/ContentArea1/VBanner/vbanner2img.png" 
/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer-home">
        <ul id="footer-nav-menu-left">
            <li><a class="nav-button-footer" href="#RegisterLeague">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-button-footer" href="#RegisterLeague">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-button-footer" href="#RegisterLeague">Press Inquiry</a> 
</li>

        </ul>
        <ul id="footer-nav-menu-right">

            <li><a class="nav-button-footer" href="#RegisterLeague">Terms of Use</a>
</li>
            <li><a class="nav-button-footer" href="#RegisterLeague">Privacy Policy</a>
</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="SocialMedia">Follow Us</div>
        <div id="Facebook-icon">
            <img src="img/SocialMediaIcon/FB_icon.png" alt="Facebook" /></div>
        <div id="Twitter-icon">
            <img src="img/SocialMediaIcon/Twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter" /></div>
        <div id="Instagram-icon">
            <img src="img/SocialMediaIcon/IG_icon.png" alt="Instagram" /></div>
        <div id="YouTube-icon">
            <img src="img/SocialMediaIcon/YouTube_icon.png" alt="YouTube" /></div>



    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Click the link below to see how it currently looks:
http://www.micre8tivegroup.com/default.html

Comment: Create a demo please.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried going through JBin but I dont know how to upload images..Is there another site I can use?

Comment: Don't use images, substitute with background colors. The images are not mandatory, only the positioning of the links.

Comment: Here is the demo. I just put it on one of our test domains.

Comment: http://www.micre8tivegroup.com/default.html

Comment: Honestly, I am having a hard time visualizing what you you want. I don't know if the problem is with the vertical or horizontal positioning. What is the proper place? At the bottom of the page? aligned with the content?

Comment: Currently the menu links at the bottom move when you re size your browser. The left edge of the footer menu links should line up with the left edge of the standard menu links. Currently if you readjust your browser screen the footer menu links will move to the center of the footer. I would like it to stay at the left edge. Sorry if I am not very clear. I have self taught myself how to code by searching Google or watching videos so I don't know all the proper Terminology.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way -it's great that you self taught coding (I learnt HTML by myself too), and I encourage you to continue- but the code is such a mess that rewriting the whole thing almost sounds like a great idea: the CSS should be in a separate file, the included jQuery files are the same just changing the target id and interval (why?), the code structure is poor (e.g.: the header is empty followed by the header logo and navigation), and there's a dangerous number of "unnecessary" `position:absolute` (most probably the root cause of the problem described in the question)...

Comment: Monty you have to start some where right... I'm starting here. The CSS is in a separate file for this demonstration I put it in the document. I am just learning positioning elements, hence the "unnecessary" position:absolute. If you have any real input as to how I can fix the issue it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing on the comments section, this is not a single thing issue. This is a problem with many things being done incorrectly. But mainly:

- The structure of the page is poorly designed. I understand that this page is more of testing, but creating a web site is not directly getting into coding but analyzing and designing a solution. Coding may be the "fun part", but it's not the most important.
- The positioning of the elements is incorrect. As a personal recommendation: avoid using `position:absolute` for controls. In your page, the logo is a good example of position absolute (although it could be done in other ways), all the rest absolute positioning shouldn't be there and breaks the page.

Here you have a link to a version the solves the position problems that you commented about: http://muzaw.com/test.html. Test it, and let me know if that's what you were aiming for (I know not everything will fit perfectly but that's just a matter of changing some values in the CSS).

The changes that I made:

- Removed the position absolute for the header and footer (or changed to `position:relative`)
- Restructured the page to fit a "more convenient" web page design.
- Changed the CSS of some of the elements.

I understand you are learning, that I sound patronizing, and that my comments and answer may frustrate you; but if you start learning bad things from the beginning, it will be worse later.

Comment: +1 This solution is much more efficient than mine. "Better far to teach a hungry man to fish than to give him a fish already caught."

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do what you want, but the header and the footer will be the same width as your mainContainer.

Just change your CSS to :

```
#footer-home
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Put it back to 0 */
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(img/footerimg.png);
}

#maincontainer
{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Add the code below */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

That way, the footer will always stay at the bottom.